# Laravel 7 Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client()

Tags: php, laravel, email

**Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known**

Comment: MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=****
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used wrong `MAIL_HOST` for gmail, please use the following configuration, and make use that your Gmail has less secured app access enabled.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=SMTP
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=ENTER_YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS(GMAIL)
MAIL_PASSWORD=ENTER_YOUR_GMAIL_PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=SSL
```

To enable less secured app:
Login to your Google Email Account and click on Google Account Button. This button is display when you click on the profile picture in your Gmail Dashboard as shown.
Once you are on My Account Page then click on Security and scroll down to the bottom and you will find ‘Less secure app access’ settings. Click on the radio button to set it ON.

Comment: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Comment: Did you clear cache after changing the `.env` file? It seems it's still using `smtp.gmail.com` as host.
Please use `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` to clear config cache.

Comment: I followed everything and kept getting the same.

Comment: Can you please go to `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file and search for `'driver' => 'smtp',` and post what the array contains?

Comment: not found from 'driver' => 'smtp'

Comment: Run `php artisan config:cache` in your cli.